# Is there a way to get rid of Nemo (file manager) theme warning?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, themes, filemanager, nemo

Every time I open a directory in Nemo-desktop, Nemo file manager opens up, but also a new terminal is opened saying:

```bash
** (nemo:36368): WARNING **: 21:28:24.724: Current gtk theme is not known to have nemo support (Adwaita-Dark) - checking...

** (nemo:36368): WARNING **: 21:28:24.809: The theme appears to have no nemo support.  Adding some...
```

Is there any way to stop this terminal from opening up or disabling all the warnings?

Comment: The message is clear enough. `nemo` doesn't have support of the theme.

Comment: @Pilot6 I just want to turn off these warnings, they are annoying and the program is running perfectly

Comment: Are you running it from a terminal? You can make an alias and redirect output to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @Pilot6 No I double click the folder icon in Nemo desktop

Comment: You need to check the `.desktop` file with which you open `nemo`. That a terminal opens in parallel is surely not normal. Run `locate nemo.desktop` for the location of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I always run a Nemo process in the background right after I log into the computer with the following command:

```
nemo . &> /dev/null &
```

As a result every time I open the Nemo File Manager later, no message is displayed and there is only one Nemo process running in the background. This is how I get rid of the Nemo (file manager) theme warning message. I use Ubuntu MATE 20.04

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks to [Plumo's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407821/is-there-a-way-to-get-rid-of-nemo-file-manager-theme-warning#comment2445566_1407821) I found that `nemo.desktop` contained the line `Terminal=true`. I changed that to `Terminal=false` and it is working fine now.

<sup>Answer derived from OP's comment.</sup>

Comment: Mine already has that set to false but I'm still getting this issue.